# How to get rid of Jagged edges in objects

Tags: modeling

[image]

How do I fix this? There jagged edges in all my objects, I have no idea what's wrong as I'm a newbie.

I was modeling and I realized there jagged edges midway, I did not use any nodes at all.

Comment: there's no anti aliasing, pixels are square so yeah that happens. Check your user preferences? Or if you're rotating around, blender won't anti alias the viewport.

Comment: [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org) Please don't post photos of your monitor, these are hard to read because we can't tell if we are looking at a reflection, a screen artifact or an actual issue with the model.

Answer (score 3):

You can adjust that in Blender Preferences (Edit -> Preferences -> Viewport -> Quality):
[image: Viewport Quality in Blender]

Comment: Hi, I changed it but it still doesnt work. maybe i'll upload again but with the blender file